# Explain if the following processes are stable or not

Tags: homework, stability

I have got a question about my homework and was wondering if anybody could help. In the picture below you can see the processes. I need to determine whether they are stable or not.

[image]

Now I have only been able to get to this point (see next picture):

[image]

When a>0 the system should be stable. So looking back at the second process, this one should be stable too (because a = 10). However, when checking the anwsers, it says both the second and third process are not stable.

Could anybody explain how I can continue the second- & begin the third process?

With regards

Comment: Refer to Routh-Hurwitz (R-H) Criterion for stability.